# How to auto-collapse all list items, when another one is expanded using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a multi-level list as:

```
<ul id="tree">
 <li><a href="#">A.</a>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Activist</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Advertising</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">code</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">theme</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Algeria</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">forest</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3.1</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">canyon</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">forest</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">river</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">3.2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">cc</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">4.1</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">5.1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">5.2</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">6.1</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">bcc</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">acc</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">American Samoa</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">B.</a>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Back Stabbing</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bad</a></li>
</ul>
```

I am using [explr-js](https://github.com/faisalman/explr-js) plugin to create a explorer tree like this:

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYbQy.png)

What I want is to auto-collapse the list, if another list item is expanded.
Currently I have this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tree > li').click(function() {
    $('li').not(this).children('ul').hide('fast');
  });
});
```

[not auto-collapsing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Pq66.png)

This code only works on first level `li` child of my main `ul` and does not work on other levels. I want to apply this to every level of the list.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This code only works on first level li child of my main ul and does not work on other levels

That's because, you are only targeting the first level of your list, if you want to target other levels, you can do like this:

```
$('ul#tree > li > ul > li').click(function() { //targets 2nd level of list
  $('ul#tree > li > ul > li').not(this).each(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').hide('fast');
  });
});
```

or

```
$('ul#tree > li > ul > li > ul > li').click(function() { //targets 3rd level of list
  $('ul#tree > li > ul > li > ul > li').not(this).each(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').hide('fast');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use the plugin , you should follow their instruction to collapse

do you set startcollapsed true?

```
$('.explr').explr({
    startCollapsed : true,
    treeHeight : 200,
    treeWidth : 400
});
```

and if you want auto close when other branch is open, you should rewrite the plugin source code, or use other plugin that has this option .maybe you can use this code!

```
$('#tree').click(function() {
  $('ul').not(this).each(function(){
     $(this).css( "display", "none" );
 });
   $(this).css( "display", "block" );
});
```

Comment: startCollapsed only means to start the tree collapsed or not, plus the plugin does not  have any instructions to collapse/expand like i want

Comment: do you want to collapse other ul tag?

like this?

  $('#tree').click(function() {
 
     $('ul').not(this).each(function(){
         $(this).css( "display", "none" );
     });
     $(this).css( "display", "block" );
  });

Comment: each time you expand a ul tag , this tag get inline style display block and if you id you want to collapse the other one you should set display none, i add the code to answer